# vrdude stk 500 not responding error inspeed control of dc motor using arduino uno board .how to solve this issue

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

vrdude stk 500 not responding error inspeed control of dc motor using arduino uno board  .how to solve this issue

[image]

[image]

Comment: ...COM1...? Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes i do only one usb port in the system

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?